# R - Grouping dataframe by ID, counting number of records in beginning and ending date ranges for each ID

Tags: r, dplyr

*Note that I've already written some code using dplyr to do what I need, but it feels very clunky and I'm wondering if there's a more elegant solution*

I have a dataframe that, simplified, is essentially this :

```
df = data.frame(
  id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
  date = as.Date(c('2018/01/01', '2018/01/02', 
      '2018/01/03', '2018/01/01', '2018/01/02', '2018/06/01'))
)
```

```
  id       date
1  1 2018-01-01
2  1 2018-01-02
3  1 2018-01-03
4  2 2018-01-01
5  2 2018-01-02
6  2 2018-06-01
```

I want to get a table that shows, for each id, the number of records within 30 days of the first record and the number of records within 30 days of the last record. For this simple version, the output should look like this:

```
id  start.records   end.records
1   3               3
2   2               1
```

I can get the output I want with this code:

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(min.date = min(date)) %>%
  mutate(min.date.plus.30 = min.date + 30) %>%
  fuzzy_left_join(
    df,
    by = list(x=c("id", "min.date.plus.30"), y=c("id", "date")),
    match_fun = list(`==`, `>`)
  ) %>%
  group_by(id.x, min.date) %>%
  summarize(start.records = n()) %>%
  left_join(
    df %>%
      group_by(id) %>%
      summarize(max.date = max(date)) %>%
      mutate(max.date.minus.30 = max.date - 30) %>%
      fuzzy_left_join(
        df,
        by = list(x=c("id", "max.date.minus.30"), y=c("id", "date")),
        match_fun = list(`==`, `<`)
      ) %>%
      group_by(id.x, max.date) %>%
      summarize(end.records = n()),
    by = "id.x"
  )
```

But it seems like a very inelegant solution.

Is there a better way to do this? I'd rather not use sqldf as it doesn't handle date calculations easily, and my real dataset has 150,000+ rows and even simple sqldf test queries take forever to run.

thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Any of the sqldf back ends other than sqlite handle dates easily.  Try H2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be we can use

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
setDT(df)[, .(start.records = sum(date <=  (first(date) + days(30))), 
       end.records = sum(date >= (last(date) - days(30)))), by = id]
#   id start.records end.records
#1:  1             3           3
#2:  2             2           1
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   summarise(
       start.records = sum(date <=  (first(date) + days(30))), 
       end.records = sum(date >= (last(date) - days(30))))
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#     id start.records end.records
#  <dbl>         <int>       <int>
#1     1             3           3
#2     2             2           1
```

Comment: hey that's pretty slick, and also feels a lot more like the SQL query I had in my mind. Guess it's time for me to read up on data.table

Comment: for any curious future googlers, this sort of logic doesn't work in SQL Server or MySQL. Putting MIN or MAX within COUNT or SUM throws an error. Looks like this is a special R ability